# "А мне фиолетово"

Tags: жаргон, фразеология

Есть такое сленговое выражение, означающее "мне все равно" — "мне фиолетово". Интересно, откуда оно могло пойти и при чем тут фиолетовый цвет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего конкретной причины нет.

заслуживает внимание мнение Грамоты: «Фиолетово – это метафора. Фиолетовый – значит "причудливый, непривычный"» и существовние некой неполитической организации "фиолетового" цвета: «во-первых, это красивый цвет, а во-вторых, потому что уже есть красные, коричневые, зеленые и голубые и на всех них лежит оттенок экстремизма».

(цитируется отсюда: [откуда пошло выражение а мне фиолетово? | Ответы Mail.Ru](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/19889019))

Но по большому счету это все мелковато для исчерпывающего объяснения, к тому же последнее скорее следствие, а не причина "фиолетового отношения".

Answer (score 1):

В книге Кандинского "О духовном в искусстве" есть такой пассаж.

В среде художников на вопрос о самочувствии отвечают иногда шутя: "Совершенно фиолетовое", что не означает ничего отрадного.

Так что "мне фиолетово" — это возрождение даже не очень забытого.

Comment: Помогу автору ответа. Вот сылка: http://www.lib.ru/CULTURE/KANDINSKIJ/kandinskij.txt_with-big-pictures.html

Comment: Хотя смысл тут разный: "мне фиолетово" — "мне все равно", "совершенно фиолетовое самочувствие" — "ничего отрадного". Скорее всего, нет связи, каждый вариант родился независимо.

Answer (score 0):

Сдаётся, что это — причёсывание ФИГА (ФИГИ) и его вариаций с предлогами и без них. По времени возникновения слегка (лет на пять-десять) опережает БЛИНОВ, причесавших в своё время БЛЯХ — заменителей другого исходного непотребства.